# Colorbox return html after content is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, colorbox

This issue i think is quite simple to solve, but i can't figure it out by my self.

I am using `colorbox` and simple `ajax` request to load some html from the server like so:

```
$.colorbox({
            href: false,
            scrolling:false,
            html: function(){
                $.post("image/render_image", {data: cardData},
                    function(response){
                        alert("I got response!");
                    }, "json"
                );

                return "I got displayed before response got back :/";
            }
        });
```

Now i am sending post request and only once i got response i want to return some `html` to the `colorbox` how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.colorbox({
    href: "image/render_image",
    data: {data: cardData},
    scrolling:false,
    onComplete: function() {
        // do what do you want
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you didn't thought about doing this way, at first i wanted to generate my html with `js` but now i see it would be a lot easier to do it with php

Comment: request is GET when you send data like Ricardo said

Comment: it works for content, but not for content within the content, i.e. load html and says "loaded" but the images within the html page aren't loaded yet